Django Bootstrap Datepicker Plus. Set maxDate as another DatePicker value plus 2 years
I need to set maxDate for DatePickerInput as another DatePickerInput value plus 2 years.
From the documentation I've learned, that we can use link to another datepicker to set minDate (range_from attribute), but I'm not sure how to set maxDate like that.
Can we do something like this?
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus.widgets import DatePickerInput
from .models import Event
from django import forms
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

class ToDoForm(forms.Form):
    start_date = forms.DateField(widget=DatePickerInput())
    end_date = forms.DateField(widget=DatePickerInput(range_from="start_date",
                                       options={
                                                   'maxDate': start_date.date + relativedelta(years=2)
                                               }))


I would suggest implementing your own widget for the date picker for additional customization. That way you have total control over it
